# ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true); why it give me error?

Tags: flutter, dart

After watching a video on youtube about designing the login page of an app, I copied the code line by line, but this two lines of login.dart give me an error. What this two lines mean ?

```
ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil.getInstance()..init(context);
ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
```

This is login.dart page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';


class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil.getInstance()..init(context);
    ScreenUtil.instance =
        ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, right: 20.0),
                child: Image.asset("assets/login_logo.png"),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(),
              ),
              Image.asset("assets/image_02.png")
            ],
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(28.0, 50.0, 28.0, 0.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset("assets/logo.png")
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I add the Screen Util packge **flutter_screenutil: ^1.0.2** in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Could you share link to the video?

Comment: [link](https://youtu.be/1Pw_E7T9TXI)
This is the link.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

In this video the old version of `flutter_screenutil` is used: `0.7.0`.
You're using `1.0.2` and the API [has been changed in `1.0.0`](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_screenutil/commit/80a660c9f78989732a9746ba1e34098acd95bc58#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8L51-R69).

So, instead of:

```dart
ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil.getInstance()..init(context);
ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
```

you should use:

```dart
ScreenUtil.init(context, width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
```

And, instead of:

```dart
ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(...); // or .setHeight(...)
```

you should use:

```dart
ScreenUtil().setWidth(...); // or .setHeight(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply is removed in newer versions, and for your question, these lines are used to get an instance of screenutil, set a design size for the screen and allow font scaling (if you want).

In the latest version that is `flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.3+2`, the code is something like this

```dart
ScreenUtil.init(
    context,
    designSize: Size(340, 700),
    minTextAdapt: true,
  );
```